# Use of time_ago_in_words in ActionMailer template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

How do I access time_ago_in_words from the email template in my rails app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
def YourNotifierClass < ActionMailer::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
  ...
end
```

to include date helper.